# Accounting for input between list values in a binary search algorithm for numbers

Tags: go

I'm trying to write a program that uses binary search to find the index of an inputted number in a list of every prime below 100, I've accounted for input above and below the maximum but I'm not sure how I would go about accounting for numbers that are in between values in the list.

```
func findPrime() int {

    primes := []int{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17,
        19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59,
        61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97}

    var num int

    fmt.Println("Choose a prime number less than 100:")

    fmt.Scanln(&num)

    for i := len(primes) / 2; ; {

        if primes[i-1] == num {

            return i - 1

        } else if primes[i] == num {
        
            return i
        
        } else if i == len(primes) && primes[i-1] != num || i == 1 && primes[i-1] != num {

            fmt.Println("Number is not a prime number less than 100, try again.")

            return findPrime()

        } else if primes[i-1] > num {

            i -= len(primes[:i]) / 2

            fmt.Println(i)

        } else {

            i += len(primes[i:]) / 2

            fmt.Println(i)

        }

    }

}
```

For example, if I enter the number 6 the code loops printing 13 7 4 2 over and over again.

I was thinking I could add the i values to a list and check if it repeats but I want to know if there is a more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: You need two indexes determining the range to search in `primes`, not the `i`, which is always the center of the range. You should make the range smaller in each iteration.